# What factors can affect different containers processing on one machine at the same time?

Tags: linux, nginx, docker, containers

For example, I have a 4vCPU, 8GB mem VM. At first, I ran a Nginx container on it and then used a stress test tool to continuously send requests to it and got some information like QPS, average latency. Then I ran three same Nginx containers on the VM and parallelly send the same requests above to these containers.I found that the respective QPS all decreased, and average latency all increased.

So what factors can affect different containers processing on one machine at the same time? I think the CPU and memory are enough to provide resources to these containers. What factors below the docker can affect these?

Comment: Sending three times as much traffic would seem to be the biggest factor.

Comment: I mean, you also share the resources of a VM with the host, if this is a public Hoster, it can restrict the resources to any hardware limit if they like.

Comment: But I just sent the same traffic to respective nginx containers like the only one nginx containers are running on that host, there were no three times as much traffic.I think most factors are these containers shared cpu time slice, so they are running serially in general and didn't monopolize a cpu core each. Of course there are more complicated than I said, just for example.

Comment: How does base linux scheduler schedule each thread to cpu?